# Не понимаю как использовать configparser в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

Мне нужно заюзать конфиги в коде, но print не хочет мне вывести что вообще в конфиге есть. Смотрел в дебаггере - qw и we уже передает пустой лист. Что делать?

```py
with open(path_configs + 'config_1.ini', 'r') as config_file:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    qw = config.read(config_file)
    we = config.sections()
    er = config['KEYS']
    print(er)
```

Пишет

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User3/PycharmProjects/untitled/script.py", line 29, in <module>
    er = config['KEYS']
  File "C:\Users\User3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'KEYS'
```

Собственно кофиг

```
[KEYS]
a = b
f = h
...
```

Comment: Метод read принимает в качестве аргумента путь к файлу конфигурации или список путей к файлам конфига. Вы же передаете ему объект файла, поэтому у вас не загружается конфиг и происходит ошибка. Попробуйте заменить метод read на read_file либо передайте ему строку пути к файлу.

Comment: @godva, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `read` принимает в качестве аргумента строку пути к файлу или список путей к файлам настроек.

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(path_configs + 'config_1.ini')

print(config['KEYS'])
# <Section: KEYS>

print(config['KEYS']['a'])
# b
```

Comment: Только хотел спросить про <Section: KEYS>, но вы меня опередили) Спасибо

Comment: Еще вопрос, а как вывести все "ключ: значения" из [KEYS] и просто ключи, и просто значения? Одним вызовом весь список
a = b
f = h
...

Comment: Каждый раздел в конфиге похож на словарь (есть [различия](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access)), поэтому к нему можно применять методы словаря. Только в результате вы всё равно получите итератор.

Answer (score 1):

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(path_configs + 'config_1.ini')

for key in config.sections():  
    print([i+'=>'+config[key][i] for i in config[key]])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]